# Can someone explain why it would not execute the last else if statement in my binary search

Tags: c, if-statement, binary-search

When i run this and try to search for a name that isnt in the structure it does not perform the else if statement, it does nothing.

```
if(first <= last) {

        while(first<= last){

            middle = (first + last)/2;

            if(strcmp(name, pSRecord[middle]->LastNames) == 0){

                printf("The Following Record Was Found: \nName: %s %s \nStudent ID: %d \nStudent Grade: %d \n", pSRecord[middle]->FirstNames, pSRecord[middle]->LastNames, pSRecord[middle]->IDNums, pSRecord[middle]->Marks);
                exit(0);

            } else if (strcmp(name, pSRecord[middle]->LastNames) > 0){

                first = middle + 1;

            } else if (strcmp(name, pSRecord[middle]->LastNames) < 0){

                last = middle - 1;

            }
        }
    } else  if{

        printf("No Record Found With The Last Name %s. \n", name);
        exit(0);

    }
```

Comment: This shouldn't even compile. `... } else if { ...` is a syntax error

Comment: And after it does compile, you only make the `if (first < last)` test once, so there's no way it will ever trigger that else clause.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46674368/7076153, :thinking:

Comment: @Kevin why? how? :o

Comment: @FelixPalmen read twice.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Also wondered, but was embarrassed to ask :) *Update:* Now got it.

Comment: @Stargateur nevermind, didn't look at this "interesting" last block ;) (so this was meant literally ... wow)

Comment: Post enough code and data for others to compile/run, else this post is un-salvageable

Comment: To trigger the `printf("No Record Found With The Last Name %s. \n", name);`, enter a array size of 0.

Answer (score 0):

while this is should not even compile because the (...} else if {...)

but ignoring that, why you have if(first <= last) and while(first <= last)?

while(first <= last) only works just fine

your code should look like

```
while(first<= last){

        middle = (first + last)/2;

        if(strcmp(name, pSRecord[middle]->LastNames) == 0){

            printf("The Following Record Was Found: \nName: %s %s \nStudent ID: %d \nStudent Grade: %d \n", pSRecord[middle]->FirstNames, pSRecord[middle]->LastNames, pSRecord[middle]->IDNums, pSRecord[middle]->Marks);
            exit(0);

        } else if (strcmp(name, pSRecord[middle]->LastNames) > 0){

            first = middle + 1;

        } else if (strcmp(name, pSRecord[middle]->LastNames) < 0){

            last = middle - 1;

        }
    }
```

putting it in a function that returns the index of it if it exist, or -1 if it's not, and you are done

Comment: OP has `if(first <= last) {` to test for an initial error condition.  It would have been better if OP posted more complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from this invalid construction

```
else  if{
```

the outer if statement does not make sense because the variables `first` and `last` are being changed in the while loop.

Just remove it

```
    while(first<= last){

        middle = (first + last)/2;

        if(strcmp(name, pSRecord[middle]->LastNames) == 0){

            printf("The Following Record Was Found: \nName: %s %s \nStudent ID: %d \nStudent Grade: %d \n", pSRecord[middle]->FirstNames, pSRecord[middle]->LastNames, pSRecord[middle]->IDNums, pSRecord[middle]->Marks);
            exit(0);

        } else if (strcmp(name, pSRecord[middle]->LastNames) > 0){

            first = middle + 1;

        } else if (strcmp(name, pSRecord[middle]->LastNames) < 0){

            last = middle - 1;

        }
    }

    printf("No Record Found With The Last Name %s. \n", name);
    exit(0);
```